# How can I define a function pointer that takes the same arguments and return value as a given function?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

For example, I have a function `foo`:

```
int foo(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

I can define a function pointer:

```
int (*pfoo)(int, int);
```

But how can I do this dynamically in program?
I want a function that takes a function as a parameter, and return a function pointer that takes the same arguments and return value as a given function.
Then I can use it like this:

```
void* pfoo = getFuncPtrFromFunc(foo);
```

Which does what the code above did.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want. If you want a pointer to a function you can just do something like this: `int (*pfoo)(int, int) = &foo`. Then you can use `pFoo` to call the `foo` function. I'm not convinced that the `getFuncPtrFromFunc()` is a good use case for whatever it is you want, because it throws type-safety out the window.

Comment: What would you do with the result?

Comment: Why do you *need* such a function? Maybe someone can find a better approach to solve your underlying problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this at run-time (i.e. dynamically); remember that all types (and function pointers are types) are statically determined at compile-time.

Imagine if you *could* do this, and you somehow obtained a function-pointer whose type was variable (i.e. it could point to a `float (*)(int,int)` or a `char (*)(float)`).  How would you ever be able to call that and provide a meaningful list of arguments?

You can, however, get this information at *compile-time*; one way is to use the [Boost TypeTraits library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html).

Answer (score 0):

c++ is a static typed language, and doesn't allow to do what you want.